# find first instance of a date using regex

Tags: regex, xml, date

I'm trying to find/replace an xml file of tide data in SubmlimeText2 and I'm stumped by multiple instances of the same date. Here's a sample of the data:

```
<item>
  <date>2016/01/01</date>
  <time>06:16 AM</time>
  <predictions_in_ft>8.2</predictions_in_ft>
  <predictions_in_cm>250</predictions_in_cm>
  <highlow>H</highlow>
</item>
<item>
  <date>2016/01/01</date>
  <time>12:31 PM</time>
  <predictions_in_ft>3.0</predictions_in_ft>
  <predictions_in_cm>91</predictions_in_cm>
  <highlow>L</highlow>
</item>
<item>
  <date>2016/01/01</date>
  <time>06:13 PM</time>
  <predictions_in_ft>6.6</predictions_in_ft>
  <predictions_in_cm>201</predictions_in_cm>
  <highlow>H</highlow>
</item>
```

What I'm trying to do is preserve the first instance of the date, but remove subsequent dates to arrive at this:

```
<item>
  <date>2016/01/01</date>
  <time>06:16 AM</time>
  <predictions_in_ft>8.2</predictions_in_ft>
  <predictions_in_cm>250</predictions_in_cm>
  <highlow>H</highlow>
</item>
<item>
  <time>12:31 PM</time>
  <predictions_in_ft>3.0</predictions_in_ft>
  <predictions_in_cm>91</predictions_in_cm>
  <highlow>L</highlow>
</item>
<item>
  <time>06:13 PM</time>
  <predictions_in_ft>6.6</predictions_in_ft>
  <predictions_in_cm>201</predictions_in_cm>
  <highlow>H</highlow>
</item>
```

Any ideas? I know an xml parser of some kind would probably be more handy, but I'm a noob and this is getting the job done on time.

Comment: It seems you would need a variable-length look behind, which isn't supported by most regex engines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this pattern:

```
(?|\G(?<=(.{10})</date>\n[ ]{2})[^<]*|<date>([^<]+))(?:<(?!date>)[^<]*)*+\K<date>\1</date>\n[ ]{2}
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM3uA5/1)

If it doesn't work add `\r` before each `\n`.

Comment: The `\G`, `\K`, and `\1` are highlighted in red. The highlighting goes away when I add another `\\`, however, Sublime Text is unable to find the string.

Comment: @MattNeznanski: I have tested it with sublime text 2 (without any change and with your string) and it works well. `\G`, `\K` and `\1` are not highlighted.

Comment: Hm. I'm confused, but hopeful. I'm pasting the pattern you provided into the 'find' field, but ST2 says it's unable to find it. Maybe I'm using the wrong tool or method?

Comment: @MattNeznanski: did you push the `.*` button in ST2? Note that the pattern is designed for an indentation of two spaces (`[ ]{2}`) before the `<time>` tag (as in your example), if the indentation is different in your real file you must adapt it.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the comment about the indentation, I totally missed that in the pattern. It works brilliantly.